# Traduction française de « plug-in estimator »

Tags: traduction, anglais, mathématiques

Existe-t-il une traduction française du terme anglais « plug-in » utilisé en statistique ?
Par exemple, « plug-in estimator » signifie « estimateur obtenu à partir de la distribution empirique ».
Comment traduire « plug-in principle » ?

Le mot « empirique » pourrait convenir mais il peut être ambigu dans certains contextes.

Comment: modulaire --> principe/système/statistique modulable/ouverte. Un arrangement à trouver en fonction du contexte.  Basé sur la notion de plug-in en informatique : que l'on peut ajouter/retirer selon les besoins.

Comment: Je ne pense pas qu'il existe de terme consacré. Dans un article mathématique rédigé en Français, je mettrais "estimateur << plug-in >>" avec des guillemets si il est mentionné une fois, et sans guillemets, dans par ex. "Définition: Un estimateur *plug-in* est blah blah", en italique, si il doit être mentionné plusieurs fois.

Comment: Je pense que Alexandre C. a raison.  J'ai vu la tournure ««plug-in» estimateur» utilisé souvent dans des articles rédigés en français, [e.g. pg. 152 2e para. de cet article](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/ads-annonces/12-001-x/9547-fra.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je n'y connais absolument rien, mais ça semble vouloir dire **estimation par insertion**.

Cette [requête google](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=estimation%20par%20insertion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=fr&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&pq=estimation%20par%20insertion&cp=46&gs_id=47&xhr=t&q=%22estimation%20par%20insertion%22%20%22plug-in%20estimator%22&pf=p&client=ubuntu&hs=JI7&channel=fs&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22estimation%20par%20insertion%22%20%22plug-in%20estimator%22&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=1483b36f4ba0cbc5&biw=1366&bih=529) (soit une recherche avec l'expression *"estimation par insertion" "plug-in estimator"*) vous permettra de valider ou invalider ma réponse.